# Merge PDF in ConvertAPI using Google Apps Script

Tags: api, rest, google-apps-script, convertapi

I'm attempting to merge two PDF files from Google Drive via ConvertAPI with the following code. Both pdf1 and pdf2 are file objects.

```
function mergePDFs(pdf1,pdf2){
  const formData = ""

  formData['Files[0]'] = pdf1.getBlob();
  formData['Files[1]'] = pdf2.getBlob();

  Logger.log(formData['Files[0]']);
  Logger.log(formData);

  endpoint = "https://v2.convertapi.com/convert/pdf/to/merge?Secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&StoreFile=true"

  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : formData,
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  };

  Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint,options));
}
```

To which I receive the following error code:

```
{"Code":4000,"Message":"Parameter validation error.","InvalidParameters":{"Files":["Files array item count must be greater than 0."]}}
```

It should be noted both Logger.log() statement come up empty. It appears to me that assignments of pdf1 and pdf2 to formData['Files[index]'] are not

I have modified the following lines considerably as I'm not familiar with this syntax, but it was referenced on [another Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71670970/merge-pdf-in-convertapi-using-google-apps-script).

```
  formData['Files[0]'] = pdf1.getBlob();
  formData['Files[1]'] = pdf2.getBlob();
```

I'm also finding that the declaration of formData is inconsequential regardless of whether it's declared as an array or as a string.

Lastly, the [pertinent documentation](https://www.convertapi.com/pdf-to-merge) from ConvertAPI says:

> Files to be converted. Value can be URL or file content. If used in >query or multipart content parameter must be suffixed with index >e.g. Files[0], Files[1](https://www.convertapi.com/pdf-to-merge), Files[2]...

The following lines from the main function are the pertinent ones to the function in question:

```
  //lodgingRecieptId is set to a url
  const receiptFile = DriveApp.getFileById(lodgingReceiptId);

  ...

  const copyID = frontPage.makeCopy().getId();
  const copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyID)
  copyDoc.setName("MPD | " + sheet.getLastRow());
  const body = copyDoc.getBody();

  //find and replace in template copy
  body.replaceText("{{AMOUNT}}",amount)
  body.replaceText("{{CURRENT_DATE}}",current_date)
  body.replaceText("{{LOCATION}}",location)
  body.replaceText("{{PURPOSE}}",purpose);
  body.replaceText("{{DEPART_DATE}}",formatLeaveDate);
  body.replaceText("{{RETURN_DATE}}",formatReturnDate);
  body.replaceText("{RSB}   ",rsb);
  body.replaceText("{{DAYS}}",days);
  body.replaceText("{{MPD_AMOUNT}}",mpdAmount);

  const docBlob = copyDoc.getAs('application/pdf');
  docBlob.setName(copyDoc.getName() + ".pdf");
  const copyPdf = DriveApp.createFile(docBlob);

  //merge lodging receipt and template copy ——> Save id
  mergePDFs(copyPdf,receiptFile)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your showing script and [your showing official document](https://www.convertapi.com/pdf-to-merge), how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please replace `<YOUR SECRET HERE>` with your secret.

```js
function mergePDFs(pdf1, pdf2) {
  var fileValues = [pdf1.getBlob(), pdf2.getBlob()].map((e, i) => ({
    "Name": e.getName() || `sample${i + 1}`,
    "Data": Utilities.base64Encode(e.getBytes())
  }));
  var data = { "Parameters": [{ "Name": "Files", "FileValues": fileValues }, { "Name": "StoreFile", "Value": true }] };
  var endpoint = "https://v2.convertapi.com/convert/pdf/to/merge?Secret=<YOUR SECRET HERE>";
  var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'payload': JSON.stringify(data),
    'contentType': "application/json",
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  };
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint, options);
  var outputPDFURL = JSON.parse(res.getContentText()).Files[0].Url;
  var outputFile = UrlFetchApp.fetch(outputPDFURL).getBlob().setName("sampleOutput.pdf");
  DriveApp.createFile(outputFile);
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your secret is valid for using this API and `pdf1` and `pdf2` are the file object or the HTTPResponse object of the PDF data. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Merge PDF API](https://www.convertapi.com/pdf-to-merge)
- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: @Jacob Bauer Sorry. I modified my sample script. Could you please confirm it? When this script is run, as a test, the merged PDF file is created as a file in the root folder.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like I'm still getting an error message: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined. This is on the line that outputPDFURL is declared.

Comment: @Jacob Bauer Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the line of your error of `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.` from your reply. But, when I tested my proposed script, 2 PDF files are merged to 1 PDF file and created it as a file on the root folder. So, I cannot replicate your current issue. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. But I would like to support you. So can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Jacob Bauer For example, can you provide your whole script? Because, although I suppose that `pdf1` and `pdf2` are the file object or the HTTPResponse object of the PDF data, I cannot understand how you call `mergePDFs(pdf1, pdf2)` in your question. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this again. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: @Jacob Bauer Now, when I tested my proposed script, when the values of `pdf1, pdf2` are not the file object or the HTTPResponse object of the PDF data, I confirmed that your error of `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` occurred. But, in your showing script, `pdf1.getBlob()` and `pdf2.getBlob()` are used. So I had believed that those values might be the file object or the HTTPResponse object of the PDF data. From this situation, I guess that your current issue is due to your values of `pdf1` and `pdf2`. So, can you provide your whole script for calling `mergePDFs(pdf1, pdf2)`?

Comment: Just added in the main post above. Thank you!

Comment: @Jacob Bauer Thank you for replying. When I saw your added script, `copyPdf` and `receiptFile` of `mergePDFs(copyPdf,receiptFile)` are `const copyPdf = DriveApp.createFile(docBlob)` and `const receiptFile = DriveApp.getFileById(lodgingReceiptId)`, respectively. From your script, I can confirm that `copyPdf` is the file object of PDF file. But I cannot know about `receiptFile`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Yes, receiptFile is also a PDF in this case.

Comment: Actually, upon further review, receiptFile was a .jpg, and all is working well now. Many, many thanks for your help on this!